# trouble while using jquery mCustomScrollbar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I met some trouble while using that plugin.

In fact I use for some reason a jquery hover background and, the initial size was 440px

[image]

When I do mouseover it works fine.

Then using the jquery scrollbar plugin, it reduce the size by adding a div called with a class `mCSB_container`

the size is auto in the css, but when I force it or change it, it does not work, so my css effect works in this reduced div, and it does not looks as expected.

I do not know how to fix this size, even the auto does not respect the size of the child.

this is how I call the plugin

```
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){

        $("#new_members").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme:"minimal"
        }).scrollbox({
            linear: true,
            step: 1,
            delay: 0,
            speed: 100
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

I do not know how to force the size of the container like in the picture above.

the css of the container added by the plugin that reduce my container below

```
.mCSB_container {
overflow: hidden;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.